# onRowClick for react-bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Trying to get onRowClick to work, but nothing is happening when I click on the row.

```
    <BootstrapTable data={products} onRowClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this)} striped={true} hover={true} pagination={true} search={true} searchPlaceholder="Search">
        <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField="_id">Customer ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="customername" >Customer Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="address">Address</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="city">City</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="createdate">Last Order Date</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="style">Style</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="dimensions">Dimensions</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry just figured it out

have to set options

```
var options = {
 onRowClick: function(row){
 }
}

<BootstrapTable data={products} options={options} ...
```

Answer (score 5):

For me I am using `react-bootstrap-table-next` - `v 4.0.3` and the above solution didn't work for some reason. Where as the following implementation worked.

```
const tableRowEvents = {
   onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
     console.log(`clicked on row with index: ${rowIndex}`);
   },
   onMouseEnter: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
     console.log(`enter on row with index: ${rowIndex}`);
   }
}

<BootstrapTable
      hover
      bordered={false}
      bootstrap4
      keyField={"apps.App"}
      data={apps ? apps : no_Data}
      columns={columns}
      rowEvents={ tableRowEvents }
/>
```

I followed the documentation from [react-bootstrap-table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Rows&selectedStory=Row%20Event&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `onRowClick`. It works fine to add an `onClick` to your `tr`s. Don't forget to use `stopPropagation` on the buttons/links inside the table to not override their action.

Answer (score 1):

For the new `react-bootstrap-table2`:

```
const rowEvents = {
  onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
    ...
  }
}

<BootstrapTable data={data} columns={columns} rowEvents={rowEvents} />
```